# Selenium - Extension method for ExpectedConditions not recognized, or: better alternatives?

Tags: c#, selenium, extension-methods

I would like to add some custom [ExpectedConditions](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/dotnet/src/support/UI/ExpectedConditions.cs) to my Selenium project.
Extension methods seem like the easiest way.

So this is my current code:

```
namespace SeleniumFramework.Utils
{
    public static class PageUtils
    {
        public static Func<IWebDriver, bool> TestCondition(this ExpectedConditions expectedConditions, By locator)
        {
            // do stuff here
        }
    }
}
```

Then, I'm trying to call this extension method:

```
using SeleniumFramework.Utils;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;
using OpenQA.Selenium;

namespace PageObjects
{
    public class Page1
    {
        public void Complete()
        {
           Browser.Wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.TestCondition(
           By.CssSelector("[ng-cloak]")));
           // do more stuff
        }
    }
}
```

However, this does **not** compile, because the extension method is not recognized.
What could be the reason for this? Are there alternatives which are just as clean, to add more custom ExpectedConditions?

Comment: An extension method needs an object; you can't expand with a static afaik. After all your first argument in the function is an object.

Comment: If it's a toolset there's no real reason to put it as static on _that_ class anyway. Remove the `this` argument and just use as `PageUtils.TestCondition()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added a class MyConditions which works just like the ExpectedConditions class.

So I can write code like `Browser.Wait.Until(MyConditions.ElementIs(...))`.

Answer (score 0):

I think  you could do something like this, from the Selenide project:  https://github.com/codeborne/selenide/blob/master/src/main/java/com/codeborne/selenide/conditions/Text.java